# Why some methods are recalled as self variables?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

Probably a dumb question right here.

I'm new to programming, but from my understanding we need to use *nameofthemetod()* to recall a method.

I don't understand why sometimes, using a class, this rule is not longer valid and instead we recall it using *self.nameofthemethod()*. Wasn't the self. supposed to work only for variables?

Here is an example:

```py
class Statusbar:
    def __init__(self, parent):

        self.status = tk.StringVar()                             
        self.status.set("PyText - 0.1 Gutenberg")

    def update_status(self):
        self.status.set("Your file has been saved")

    def save(self):
        self.update_status() # why the self? Shouldn't it be just update_status()?
```

Didn't paste the whole code, but I hope you get the idea

Comment: *Wasn't the self. supposed to work only for variables?* - No - it applies to methods as well.

Comment: You use `self.function ()` when defining the `class` so that it is called on an instance of that `class` similar to the variables of that class using `self.variable`.

Comment: FYI: It's "call," not "recall."

Comment: Any object including callables (for example functions) can be a "variable" (the official term in Python is "name" though).

Comment: Please note, there is nothing special about the word "self". It is just a convention (a very useful one so please follow it). But if you replaced every occurence of "self" with "instance", or with "the_name_i_like_more" it would still work exactly the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the methods (like class variables) are defined in a class and as part of the class, they must be referenced as such. When calling `update_status()` *outside* of `StatusBar`, it must be called as `StatusBar.update_status()`, because it is part of the `StatusBar` class:

```py
class Statusbar:
    def __init__(self, parent):

        self.status = tk.StringVar()                             
        self.status.set("PyText - 0.1 Gutenberg")

    def update_status(self):
        self.status.set("Your file has been saved")

    def save(self):
        self.update_status()

sb = StatusBar(some_window) # Here we create an instance of StatusBar
sb.update_status() # Here, we call StatusBar's method: update_status()
```

The same goes when calling `update_status()` from *inside* the class. `self`, as the name suggests, is simply a class's way of referencing itself. When the class calls `self.update_status()`, it's basically saying "Call *my* update_status() method." Try printing `self`; the output will be something like this:

```
<__main__.Statusbar object at 0x7efdd6445040>
```

The point is, since `update_status()` is a method, and therefore part of the class (like the variable `self.status`), it must be treated as such, whether you're calling it from inside *or* outside the class.